# Jquery modal form is not working for me in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Recently I'm starting to use jquery, when trying to popup a modal form using jquery its won't working for me, the css file and javascript files are keeping locally. Please see the code snippet below

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });

    $('#opener').click(function() {
                alert('test');
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
    });
});
</script> 

</head>
<body>        
    <?php
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">';
    ?>
    <button id="opener">Open the dialog</button>

</body>
```

Please correct me if I did any mistake. Thanks all.

Comment: does it work if you don't retrieve code from server using PHP and have a single HTML page instead?

Comment: @Able this has nothing to do with PHP, btw. HTML, sure.

Comment: so,i need to use the following link `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include:

```
modal: true,
```

in your dialog definition like this:

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('This dialog will show every time!')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Basic Dialog'
    });
```